# read files outside jar in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am trying to run application jar and have the application configurations(application.yml) externalized. There are a few files that are referenced from this application.yml.

Application run command:

```
java -Dspring.config.location=file:/absolulte/path/to/application.yml -cp ".:/path/to/app/resources" -jar /path/to/application.jar
```

Directory Structure:

```
app/
├─ resources/
│  ├─ keystore.jks
│  ├─ application.yml
├─ application.jar
```

Taking example of [Kafka Library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka/2.4.6.RELEASE) trying to access the file.

I have tried to configure the path in the following way

application.yml

```
keystore-location: classpath:keystore.jks
```

And when the library tries to access these files, I get the following error.

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [keystore.jks] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/path/to/file/application.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/keystore.jks

and with

```
keystore-location: file://keystore.jks
```

> Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4: file:/path/to/jar/application.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/keystore.jks

Instead of looking for the file in the path specified, it looks for in the jar.

Spring Kafka library was one of the examples and few other libraries too give similar errors.

SpringBoot Version: 2.2.5.RELEASE

Java Version: 1.8

Thanks

Comment: Why would you *want* a resource like that outside the jar?

Comment: The keystore and truststore files are read by Apache Kafka (kafka-clients), not Spring; see my answer.

Comment: @g00se so that I would not have to redeploy the application when there's a certificate rotation (in .jks file) Or when there's application configuration change(application.yml).

Comment: I see. Actually this *java -Dspring.config.location=file:/absolulte/path/to/application.yml -cp ".:/path/to/app/resources" -jar /path/to/application.jar* is not right. `-jar` and `-cp` are mutually exclusive. So you'd need `java -Dspring.config.location=file:/absolulte/path/to/application.yml -cp ".:/path/to/app/resources:/path/to/application.jar" a.b.c.Main`

Answer (score 0):

The keystore and truststore files are read by Apache Kafka (kafka-clients), not Spring, and must be on the file system; you have to write your own code to copy the file from the class path to the file system (e.g. /tmp) before creating the Spring application context.

There is an open issue against Apache Kafka.

It's been open a long time; voting for it might help.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7685

Comment: please notice that I'm trying to add the external resources/ directory to classpath in application run command. This probably is not a good practice, but shouldn't this ideally work?

Comment: No; it won't work. Kafka knows nothing about the `file://` prefix; the value must be an absolute path to a file on the file system.

Comment: but even with the absolute path; it is not able to read it. Error : `org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: SSL trust store is not specified, but trust store password is specified.`
with Configuration(spring.kafka.ssl):
`truststore-location: /tmp/keystore.jks
truststore-password: somepassword`

Comment: It's `trust-store-password`; if you use an IDE, you will get content assist on these well-known properties.